# Skin color detection in WebGL

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader, skin, color-detection

I want to remove from a live-stream video the background of a hand. Whatever that is. My aim is to only keep the hand which will be moving and I want it done in WebGL and GLSL shaders.

I have implemented this : https://softexpert.wordpress.com/2007/10/17/skin-color-detection/ but the results are not good. I have also implemented this : http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/2011/Mexico/CEMATH/CEMATH-20.pdf but again I would like some advice on improving it or doing something else.

Thank you.

Comment: I don'y know about skin detection but the problem feels a lot like you want to do object/border detection. Possible solution would be to detect object borders and then find objects that are mostly or nearly completely matching skin color. That would eliminated single pixel flashing if there is some random color errors. It might be able to manage to detect some tattoos to be part of skin even tough they have very different color. I don't know any good algorithm that would work with limitations that webgl has. Desktop GL/CL/Vulkan is easier environment  for many algorithms.

Comment: @PauliNieminen I actually want to process in real time a live stream which comes from a camera. And I want basically to detect the hand of a person, and remove everything else. Do you have any ideas on this?

Comment: Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection give the idea what I'm trying to propose? I haven't personally implement edge detections but it feels like possible to implement in webgl. You need multipass render that first run edge detection (maybe multi-pass too) and then later pass uses that in combination with skin color detection.

Comment: so, I know what edge detection is. How is it going to help me with live hand detection? How will I combine it with skin color detection?

Comment: Right. Algorithm that I was thinking doesn't work that well in shader world. Basic flow idea was 1. detect edges 2. Combine very small areas to larger surrounding areas 3. Calculate amount of pixels passing skin detection in each area. 4. Final rendering would only sample from video that are in an area with skin detection per cent over some threshold. But processing edge detection to areas and calculating skin detection per cent per area won't be easy. That leaves me to think that maybe it is better to apply a blur filter before skin detection....

Comment: Skin colour and luminance would still require careful. People have widely different ski colours that can cause some trouble and luminance difference come easily from different lightning around camera. But maybe it could be combination two algorithms. Real time one running simple skin detection based on blurred colour while luminance and skin colour parameter for detection would be calculated regularly in background using more expensive algorithm that could be based on edge/shape detection.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answers. Indeed intense image processing (for pattern recognition etc) is not an option due to performance problems. I am already applying a blur filter and I think it does help. I have tried HSv and yCbCr color models to avoid luminance problems and they also helped. I was just searching for any other ideas that might helped.

Comment: True. Real time image processing is very limiting. But you could try to fine tune detection threshold with more expensive background algorithm that can be run like once every 1-5 seconds. If background thread can provide better threshold values you get less false positives and negatives. A very clever background process might even manage to provide some bounding box for skin detection to avoid checking pixel very far from skin. But that would need to be combined with per frame movement vector detection to keep bounding box around skin area.

Comment: Good idea. But I forgot to inform you that the background of the hand will mostly (99%) be a solid colored surface. So I 'll have a hand and int he background a solid surface. So that's convenient right? Having this information what would you suggest to do?

Comment: Solid background color. That makes thinks a lot easier. You could aim to detect the background instead. If you want to improve your thresholds you can try to create histograms from background and skin area (in different colour spaces). Then you can select the colour space where you have most difference that allows you to use very wide thresholds and maybe only minimal blur. That of course assumes there is clear difference like movie/TV uses when using "key" colour background to combine two or more images in real time.

Comment: @PauliNieminen 2 questions : is creating histograms in GLSL easy? Is creating histograms in real time fast?

Comment: You could attach Nx1 texture to FBO. Then you can render gl.POINTS using your texture as vertex data. BlendFunction set to FUNC_ADD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527102/how-do-you-compute-a-histogram-in-webgl. But I was more like thinking you would check histograms offline in your favorite photo editing tool. You can load colorspace converted raw bitmap data that just looks funny but per channel histograms would be correct. Then you can set threshold values to closer to solid color background.